# How to improve this SQL performance?

Tags: sql, oracle

I made a query shown as below. The purpose is for a quick search for the orders. User inputs one keyword, system returns orders whose property matches that keyword. E.g. keyword = "pan", any order record related to "pan" should be returned, like order's country="Japan",or description = "This is a pan." or order's customer's name = "Pan", or there is a product named "pan" in the order.

`ORDER_TABLE`, `ORDER_DESCRIPTION`, `ORDER_COUNTRY`, these tables are one to one relationship. But `ORDER_TABLE` and `ORDER_PRODUCT` is one to many (10-100) relationship. 'ORDER_TABLE' has over 300,000 rows, so is `ORDER_DESCRIPTION`, `ORDER_COUNTRY`. `ORDER_PRODUCT` has about 1500,000 rows.

But it is extremely slow since database stores huge data.

```
SELECT ot.id, od.description, oc.country_name 
    FROM       ORDER_TABLE ot
    LEFT JOIN  ORDER_DESCRIPTION od ON ot.id = od.id
    LEFT JOIN  ORDER_COUNTRY oc     ON ot.id = oc.id
    LEFT JOIN  ORDER_PRODUCT op     ON ot.id = op.id
    WHERE ot.delete!='Y' AND od.delete!='Y' AND ot.create_date >= SYSDATE - 90
    AND
    (
        ot.id like '%KEYWORD%'
        OR UPPER(od.description) LIKE '%KEYWORD%'
        OR UPPER(ot.version) LIKE '%KEYWORD%'
        OR UPPER(oc.country_name) LIKE '%KEYWORD%'
        ...(many columns are used to match that keyword)
        OR UPPER(op.product_name) LIKE '%KEYWORD%'
    )
    GROUP BY (...)
    ORDER BY ot.id
```

This query is extremely slow. Usually it takes 35sec to process. Any idea to improve it? I heard that multiple join is not a good idea. So I tried to use nested subquery, but no big improvement.

Thanks.

Comment: The issue is probably all the LIKEs, which will ensure that any indexes on those columns won't be used. You might want to consider indexing your data using a search engine like Solr.

Comment: `LIKE` with a leading '%' is real perfomance killer. Try removing them  to confirm this is the problem.  If so, have a look at David suggestion.

Comment: To get a meaningful answer you need to post: your query's explain plan, the table indexes and the cardinality of the columns you're filtering on as an absolute minimum. Everything is guesses and potentially inaccurate without this.

Comment: Please provide which indexes are available, what is the number of records on each table, how many orders you expect to be returned since it only accounts for 90 days and the execution plan for the query.

Comment: I added more info. About index, I don't know where to check. Still need sometime to find it out.

Comment: `SELECT index_name FROM all_indexes WHERE table_name = 'ORDER_TABLE'`

`SELECT column_name FROM all_ind_columns WHERE index_name = ` etc.

Comment: I didn't find indexes for those tables by the method David suggested. But it seems indexes won't improve performance due to '%'. So except resort to Solr, are there other ways?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the AND checks in where clause directly in join

```
SELECT ot.id, od.description, oc.country_name
FROM ORDER_TABLE ot
    LEFT JOIN  ORDER_DESCRIPTION od ON ot.id = od.id AND ot.delete!='Y' AND od.delete!='Y' AND ot.create_date >= SYSDATE - 90
    LEFT JOIN  ORDER_COUNTRY oc     ON ot.id = oc.id
    LEFT JOIN  ORDER_PRODUCT op     ON ot.id = op.id
    WHERE
    (
        ot.id like '%KEYWORD%'
        OR UPPER(od.description) LIKE '%KEYWORD%'
        OR UPPER(ot.version) LIKE '%KEYWORD%'
    OR UPPER(oc.country_name) LIKE '%KEYWORD%'
    ...(many columns are used to match that keyword)
    OR UPPER(op.product_name) LIKE '%KEYWORD%'
)
GROUP BY (...)
ORDER BY ot.id
```